# Portable AC not getting ride of condensate

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a portable AC (LG lp1015wnr) which does not evaporate the condensate. It doesn't matter if it is in Dry or Cool mode. In both modes the water is drained from the drain pipe at the same rate.

------------Edit (Further explanation)---------

The AC has two drains, on in the middle and one on the bottom. Also two modes of working.
[image: modes of working]

Dry mode: Also know as dehumidifier mode. When the AC works in this mode, the condensate should be drained from the middle drain pipe (Which is a normal way of getting the water out).
[image: middle drain]

Cool mode: In this mode, the AC vaporizes the condensate, so there should not be any water coming out of the middle drain. Only when the humidity level is high, the left over condensate which is not vaporized, goes down to the pan, which can be drained from the bottom of the AC.
[image]

When my AC is working in the cool mode, I see a lot of water running from the middle drain and I have to put a bucket under it. I expect the AC to vaporize that water and have the left over on the bottom pan, but as I explain, it is not happening. The question is why is this happening? Do I have to block the middle drain?

Comment: What is your question? Does water accumulate in a reservoir which must be emptied manually? Is this contrary to what the instructions state?

Comment: In cool mode, it should evaporate the condensate. But still it is drained from drain pipe. There is no water in reservoir. So I was wondering what could the problem be.

Comment: There is no water in the reservoir? You are NOT having to empty the reservoir? Then where is the water going? Unless you see a puddle in the machine or on the floor, then the only possibility is that it is evaporating. Where is this "drain pipe" you are referring to? Where is it emptying?

Comment: Why the down vote? The op stated a simple question that the pipe flows +. Spellin is no reason for a down vote.

Comment: Why do you suppose there is there a drain pipe if you think the water should be evaporated before it can drain? What does the user manual say should be happening to the condensate ?

Comment: there are two modes. On Cool mode the condensate should be vaporized. On Dry mode the condensate should be drained from the the middle pipe.

Answer (score 2):

In cool or dehumidifier mode if you don’t have a pump you will have to dump the condensate based on your humidity, it is a basic function of cooling that there will be moisture to get rid of. 
Don’t believe me put a glass full of ice water on a table with enough ice to last 15 minutes, now look at the ring of water at the base of the glass. If you want the system to cool there WILL be water to get rid of times a hundred or even 10 thousand depending on the size or amount of cooling and humidity. In a high humidity zone the amount of condensate or water you need to get rid of can be the same. It is normal and expected with cooling or dehumidification.

Answer (score 2):

An air conditioner works by making one stream of air (in and out) cold - and another stream of air (in and out) hot.  You always get condensation on the cold side coils.

A portable A/C *tries* to get rid of that water by evaporating it over on the hot side.  That can work OK on a dry day.    **However, if the day is quite humid, it may not be able to evaporate all of it**.  Then it winds up in the condensate tank, and you must empty it.

That does not mean the A/C is broken.  It means the day is humid.

It helps if you have a 2-pipe portable air conditioner, which takes the "to be made hot" air from outside, and ejects it to outside.  But if you have a 1-pipe portable air conditioner, then it's taking the "to be made hot" air *from inside*.  That has to be replaced by air from outside coming in through cracks and leaks -- and that air is hot and humid. So your 1-pipe air conditioner is constantly dragging in new hot, humid air, and that's where all the water is coming from.   If it has a 2-pipe feature, *use it*.

Comment: Does the condensate first empty into the reservoir from which it is evaporated (say by expelled warmed air being force through the reservoir)? Or does the condensate get spread out and have the warmed air swept over it? In the latter case only the remaining water would flow into the reservoir. Put another way, once water gets into the reservoir does it stay there until the reservoir is manually emptied?

Comment: The op stated they have a drain pipe on the portable. Some models do not evaporate but put it in a tank or bucket. Dehumidified air is usually preferable but not always. high end units actually add humidity at times basted on the measured level.

Answer (score 0):

Air-conditioning units of all kinds are supposed to do 2 jobs, cool the air and remove humidity. If the unit is cooling properly, then there is water (condensate) being produced which has to be drained somewhere. If there is no condensate being produced then the A/C unit is not functioning correctly. They are not supposed to re-humidify the air to dispose of the condensate. If there is no condensate then something is wrong.

Comment: " If there is no condensate being produced then the A/C unit is not functioning correctly." Not at all! Just because there is no condensate, it did not mean the ac unit is not working correctly! Warn air can only hold so much water vapor. Once that warm air cools to the dew point or lower, the water vapor will form condensation on the evaporator coil. Once the water vapor is removed from the space, there will be no more condensation. I have seen window, split, and whole house units not produce any condensate.